# htaccess redirect of sub pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Redirects for top-level pages work fine, but now I'm looking to redirect sub-pages in a WordPress site to their new respective top level page, but I evidently don't have the correct syntax:

Old page:  websiteURL/aboutus/benefits

New page:  websiteURL/careers

After trolling through the forums, I tried this option, but no luck:

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/aboutus/benefits$ http://website.net/careers/
```

Problem: Rather than re-directing to the new absolute/static URL, the redirect just changes the folder name, so the resulting URL is simply
websiteURL/about-us/benefits.

One more example of a sub-page needing to the redirected to an absolute URL:

Old url:   websiteURL/expertise/software-engineering

New url:   websiteURL/core-competencies

```
redirectMatch 301 /expertise.* http://websiteURL/core-competencies
```

But this doesn't work.  The resulting URL is websiteURL/core-competencies/software-engineering
Meaning it changes the folder name, then adds on the page name.  No good for what we need.

Comment: That line looks fine, could it be that your dynamic configuration file is not interpreted at all by the http server? You need to enable that (`AllowOverride ...`) and store the file inside your document root such that it is readable for the server process. Even better is not to use such files at all but place the command in the host configuration itself.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that is the issue.   All other 301 redirects in the .htaccess are working as expected.   The only ones I've having trouble with are the sub-pages.  

In the above example, the result is a 404 page.